# Return Error Message from START /WAIT Command calling DTUTIL

Tags: batch-file, ssis

All,
I am using a batch file to automate the deployment of SSIS packages out to MSDB.  I am using a `START /WAIT` command in a `FOR` loop to iterate through all files in a folder and execute the `DTUTIL` command.

While I know I can return the `%ERRORLEVEL%` and use it in the main batch process, what I am losing is the specific error message that `DTUTIL` outputs.

I want to be able to capture that message output, but I have yet to find a way to.  I tried chaining commands by using the `&&`, `||` and `&` concatenation commands.  And I also tried to use `>` and `2>` to put the output into a file.  Nothing has given me the desires output.

And to be specific, I'm mainly concerned with when `DTUTIL` ERRORS and the message is more relevant than the error code alone.

Any help or recommendations would be appreciated.  Here's the code:

```
@echo off

SET /P SOURCEFOLDER=Enter the Source Folder where the Packages are located:
SET /P DESTSERVER=Enter the Destination Server:
SET /P DESTLOCATION=Enter Destination Folder (Leave blank for root):

IF NOT EXIST "%SOURCEFOLDER%\*.dtsx" GOTO NOFILES

FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%i in (`dir /b "%SOURCEFOLDER%\*.dtsx"`) do (
ECHO.
ECHO ^>^>^>^>^>^> Copying %%i to %DESTSERVER%\MSDB\%DESTLOCATION% ^<^<^<^<^<^<^<
ECHO.
START /WAIT dtutil /FILE "%SOURCEFOLDER%\%%i" /DESTSERVER %DESTSERVER% /COPY SQL;"%DESTLOCATION%\%%~ni" /QUIET
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
ECHO.
)
GOTO COMPLETE

:NOFILES
ECHO.
ECHO *** No SSIS Packages were found.  Please verify the folder location:
ECHO %SOURCEFOLDER%
ECHO.
GOTO END

:COMPLETE
ECHO.
ECHO All Packages have been Processed.
ECHO Please verify that no Error Messages or Warnings were returned.
ECHO.
GOTO END

:END
PAUSE
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: @Kiquenet I put the working code up on GitHub https://github.com/thevinnie/SSISDeploymentUtility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest would be to drop start and just issue Dtutil (since you wait till it finishes I cannot see a difference). Another two possibilites

```
start /B dtutil >result.txt
```

or

```
start cmd /c dtutil ^>result.txt
```

(^ is used to escape special chars, here redirection symbol >) (and you already use it...)

Redirect stderr would be `2>result.txt`, both stdout and strerr `>result.txt 2>&1` (escaped if used with cmd /c: `^>result.txt 2^>^&1`)

Comment: Would that same syntax apply if I wanted to send that output to a variable instead?  I've seen the usage `cmd /c: >result.txt 2>&1` before, but I'm unclear what the `&1` writes to.

Comment: @Vinnie: `>result.txt` is a shortcut for `1>result.txt`, where `1` is the number of a stream and stands for STDOUT (i.e. the entire piece of code means *‘redirect stream 1 (STDOUT) to the said file’*). `2` designates STDERR, and `2>&1` means *‘redirect stream 2 (STDERR) same as stream 1 (STDOUT)’*, in this case – to the same file.

Comment: @vinnie - it's as Andriy explained. Please note there is no : (colon) in the syntax, it's `cmd /c` You cannot directly assign command ouput to variable AFAIK (you could iterate over output with `for /f` though). I'm also not sure if dtutil writes anything to stderr. You can check by running dtutil _your_options_causing_err_ >nul

Comment: You made a good point that I don't really need the `START /WAIT`, so taking that out got me what I needed.  Simple enough.  And @wmz, I'm not sure how I stuck the `:` in there, but that was a typo. Thanks for the catch.